# Complicated countifs statement using date

Tags: excel, formula

I am working on a spreadsheet at work and I can't seem to get a formula to work.

I am trying to do a countifs using these Criteria:

If column A has "Not Received"
If column B has a date that is 60 days past today's date

I have tried using the following formula:

`=COUNTIFS(Reports!A:A,"Not Received",Reports!B:B,(TODAY()-Reports!B:B)>60)`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second condition should be reworded, as if you're already having `Reports!B:B` in the equation:

```
=COUNTIFS(Reports!A:A,"Not Received",Reports!B:B,"<"&TODAY()-60)
```

---

If you want some math...

```
Today - Date > 60

Today - 60 > Date
```

So,

```
Date < Today - 60
```

Comment: I happened to be around and no other questions to look at ^^; Thank you